# Getting "mongod: command not found". Analysis found that rpm is getting deleted

Tags: mongodb

I am evaluating mongodb  Enterprise  version. I have it running in a RedHat Linux OS. Things were going good till mongod command stopped working suddenly. Our unix admins replied that rpm is getting deleted.

Here is the information i got from admins Any idea on this?

```
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:27] Unknown lvalue 'TasksMax' in section 'Service'
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:28] Unknown lvalue 'TasksAccounting' in section 'Service'
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: Started Flexible Branding Service.
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: Starting Flexible Branding Service...
Oct 23 15:39:20  yum[93405]: Erased: mongodb-enterprise-server-3.4.9-1.el7.x86_64
Oct 23 15:39:20  yum[93405]: Erased: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-28.el7.x86_64
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: Reloading.
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: Started Flexible Branding Service.
Oct 23 15:39:20  systemd[1]: Starting Flexible Branding Service... "
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Harin

Answer (score 0):

The **systemd** introduced this ***TasksMax*** setting in **version 226**

You need to check your version *SYSTEMD*

```
sudo systemd --version or sudo systemctl --version
```

If you systemd is old that the above you need to update link to update systemd

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-systemd-centos-redhat/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Set the SELINUX variable in the /etc/selinux/config file like follows:

> SELINUX = disabled

Then restart MongoDB.
regards,